# Why does pwdx output for an apache2 process show only a slash?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webserver

I have googled for this question but not found an appropriate answer.

I am retrieving my process id with below command:

```
pwdx `ps -ef | grep -i apache2 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

It shows me output like this:

```
1722: /
30975: /var/www/insightindiacrm
31028: /var/www/bhavingem
31203: /var/www/bhavingem
31462: /var/www/bhavingem
31573: /var/www/bhavingem
31574: /var/www/outmailsv1
31575: /
31578: /var/www/bhavingem
```

Why is my apache2 process current working directory showing **slash(/)** ?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit server os.

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Because its current working directory is `/` (or, at least, what Apache believes to be `/` -- its quite possible that it's running in a `chroot`)?

Comment: In which case my current working directory show / ?

Comment: Any process can `cd /` if it wants to. (By the way, you do know that `/` is the root of the filesystem, don't you?)

Comment: @AlexP I know that / is root of file system. apache2 show pwdx as / means from coding I have changed chdir to / in my php file.

Comment: Not necessarily. I understand that you are using `mod_prefork` (because otherwise there would not be any link between the current working directory in PHP code and the CWD of Apache), but even then, not all Apache processes are involved in running PHP code.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks...... yes I am using mpm_prefork